# Get a handle for item in jQuery collection within .ajax() success function on which the call was made?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery ajax call fired for each element in a collection identified by a jQuery selector, like this:

```
$('.myClass').each(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myUrl',
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'myVar': 'myVal' },
        success: function(){    
            // this doesn't work:
            $(this).removeClass('stateChanged') 
        }
    });
});
```

I want to remove a "stateChanged" class from each element in the  $('.myClass') collection once the ajax call succeeds for that element, but I can't seem to find a way to get a handle for each specific element in the $('.myClass') collection within the success function.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `statechanged` on the same element as `myClass`?

```
$('.myClass').each(function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myUrl',
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'myVar': 'myVal' },
        success: function(){    
            $self.removeClass('stateChanged') 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? This will only remove the "stateChanged" class from the parent element; not all elements in the ".myClass" parent as the OP states.

Comment: the question is pretty unclear. i took "each element in the $('.myClass') collection" to mean each element with the class of `myClass`, not each dom node.

Comment: Sorry - don't mean to rain on your answer. Makes sense with your interpretation too.

Comment: always good to clarify things, your comment was perfectly valid.

Comment: Sorry for not chiming in earlier -- didn't notice the traffic 2 weeks ago. Wheeler's interpretation is correct. Agreed that the wording  "each element in the $('.myClass') collection" is ambiguous,  though I think the code -- $('.myClass').each() -- should have cleared that up.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.myClass').each(function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myUrl',
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'myVar': 'myVal' },
        success: function(){    
            $self.children().removeClass('stateChanged');
        }
    });
});
```

You asked for each specific element in the myClass class, right?

Answer (score 1):

you are going right, but `this` inside callback has scope inside callback function only.... so you have to keep refrence of this in a variable like this-

```
$('.myClass').each(function () {    
   var $this = $(this);    //save the reference in a variable 
   $.ajax({        
   url: 'myUrl',        
   type: "POST",        
   data: { 'myVar': 'myVal' },        
   success: function(){               
   $this.removeClass('stateChanged')  // use variable to remove class       
       }    
    });
 });
```