# jQuery ajax this.id undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a list of items I delete using AJAX.

This list is a simple list with divs and each div as an id so when the item is removed from the database I return true and then it removes the line.

Here my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="row1">
<div>item1</div>
<div><a href="...">view</a></div>
<div><a id="1">delete</a></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/delete_record',
        data: 'id=' + this.id,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 'good') {
                $('#row' + this.id).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason the `this.id` does not work because `this.id` is undefined ... why? I have `id="1"` on my a href.

Comment: There is no elements that have the class `.delete`, and if there was you would need to save the reference to `this` in the click handler, and refer to that inside the success handler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The this you are using refers to the ajax object  because there is a new scope within that function. If you want to access variables outwide your scope, you have to declare them before the ajax call.

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
        return false;
    }
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/delete_record',
        data: 'id=' + this.id,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 'good') {
                $('#row' + _this.id).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your ID should not start with a number. Here is how to formulate a valid id: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

`this` within your success callback function does not refer to the `this` in your click handler function. So you need to make a reference to `this` in your click handler so it can be accessed in your callback function:

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
        return false;
    }
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/delete_record',
        data: 'id=' + this.id,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 'good') {
                $('#row' + that.id).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm all ears about the down-vote. Just wondering how to improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

try to declare before the `$.ajax` the `$this`

like:

> var $this = this;

and use the variable.

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
   var $this = this;

  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      return false;
  }

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/delete_record',
      data: 'id=' + $this.id,
      cache: false,
      success: function (result) {
          if (result == 'good') {
              $('#row' + $yourid).remove();
          }
      }
 });
});
```

Comment: Good point but you probably don't need to wrap the `this` variable in a jQuery object since all that's needed is the ID. How about: `var that = this;` since you can use `that.id` in the AJAX callback function.

Comment: When you're getting the id of an element it creates far less overhead to do `var $thisId = this.id` instead of wrapping `this` in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
        return false;
    }

    var id = this.id; // here is the magic

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/delete_record',
        data: 'id=' + this.id,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 'good') {
                $('#row' + id).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any element with a class of 'delete' in your html.  Assuming it's the delete link, you need to get the id with `$(this).attr('id')` instead of this.id.

Comment: `this.id` returns the id without creating extra overhead making a jQuery object.