# How to traverse in jQuery within AJAX function?

Tags: jquery, traversal

I am having difficulty traversing with jQuery.  I have a form with a dynamic set of dropdown boxes, and am trying to call particular actions based on element class instead of id, as this form can be cloned in my application.

Any ideas why my traversing isn't working?  Is my `$(this)` call becoming voided somehow?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Item:</label>
    <select class="item" name="item" id="item"> 
        <option value="">Select</option>
        ...
    </select>
</div>          
<div>
    <label class="label>Options:</label>
    <select class="options" name="options" id="options">

        ...
    /select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".item").change(function () { 

  var group_id = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../../db/items.php?id=" + group_id, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $(this).parent().next().children('select.options').empty(); 
            $(this).parent().next().children('select.options').append('<option value="">Select</option>');
            $.each(data, function(i, val){    
               $(this).parent().next().children('select.options').append('<option value="' + val.group_id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
            });
            $(this).parent().next().children('select.options').focus();
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(this).parent().next().children('select.options').empty();
            $(this).parent().next().children('select.options').append('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
        },
        error: function(){
            $(this).parent().next().children('select.options').attr('disabled', true);
            $(this).parent().next().children('select.options').empty();
            $(this).parent().next().children('select.options').append('<option value="">No Options</option>');
        }
    })  

});
```

Comment: Yes, inside the callbacks, `this` refers to something else. If you want a reference to the DOM element, you have to store it earlier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

Comment: Assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is no longer the DOM element that the event was triggered on. You can set the value of `this` by using the `context` option of [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$(".item").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        /* options */
        context: this,
        success: function () {
            // this is now the element that was changed
        }
    });
});
```

You could also store the value of `this` in a variable and use it in your callback:

```
$(".item").change(function () { 

  var group_id = $(this).val();
  var self = this;

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../../db/items.php?id=" + group_id, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            // use "self" instead of "this"
        }
    })  

});
```

Another note: You should consider caching your selectors for greater performance (and readability). Also, you can chain together jQuery function calls:

```
var $children = $(this).parent().next().children('select.options')
    .empty()
    .append('<option value="">Select</option>');

$.each(data, function(i, val){    
   $children.append('<option value="' + val.group_id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
});
$children.focus();
```

Comment: I didn't now that about the context attribute in the ajax call. That seems cleaner that defining another variable as I suggested as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var group_id = $(this).val();
 var myThis = $(this);

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../../db/items.php?id=" + group_id, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            myThis.parent().next().children('select.options').empty(); 
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, $this now refers to the success function in your ajax call. Add this line.

```
$(".item").change(function () {  

  var group_id = $(this).val(); 
  var item = $(this); // Added line
```

Now in your ajax function use item where you use $this.