# $(this) not working inside the success function of ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am using ASP.NET MVC with Jquery, and this seems to be a jquery fault.

I am making an ajax call to my method, my code is

```
$('.reopenBtn').live('click', function () {
    var taskId = $(this).attr("data-taskid");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Task/ReopenTask/?strTaskId=' + taskId,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            // this does not work !!
            $(this).parent().parent().closest("div").remove();              
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

The `remove` doesn't work however when creating a jsfiddle for this question [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H5sDC/39/) , this works.

So, is `$(this)` something different inside the success function of the ajax call ?

How do I get around this ? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`context` property will work inside the success function of ajax `context: this,`

```
$('.reopenBtn').live('click', function () {
    var taskId = $(this).attr("data-taskid");
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Task/ReopenTask/?strTaskId=' + taskId,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $(self).parent().parent().closest("div").remove();              
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

Or you could set `context` property of ajax option.

```
    $('.reopenBtn').live('click', function () {
        var taskId = $(this).attr("data-taskid");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Task/ReopenTask/?strTaskId=' + taskId,
            type: "POST",
            context: this,
            success: function (data) {
                $(this).parent().parent().closest("div").remove();              
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Yesser, please xdazz, accepting the answer, if it solved your question.

Comment: Please use "delegate" or "on" instead as "live" is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this method, wrapping with $.proxy, two args are callback function and `this` as 2nd argument.

```
$.post('/foo', data, $.proxy(function(d){
  // do stuff with data
}, this));
```

I think it is shortest and cleanest.

You can do what others say above as well, either copying `this` to `that` (`self` is a reserved word) and then using in callback, or using $.ajax with `context: this` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The context of the `click` method is simply not the same as for the `success` method. Thus you do not have the same `this` in the inner function.
You can avoid that by using a local variable like `$this` or `clickedButton` and use it in your `success` method:

```
$('.reopenBtn').live('click', function () {
  var $this = $(this)
  var taskId = $this.attr("data-taskid");

  $.ajax({
    url: '/Task/ReopenTask/?strTaskId=' + taskId,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        // $this is taken from the outer function context
        $this.parent().parent().closest("div").remove();              
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Error');
    }
  });
});
```

For detailed explanation you might want to take a look at [Closures in JavaScript](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)