# $(this) object not available in AJAX callback

Tags: ajax, jquery, closures, jquery-callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

I am using one button click in which an ajax call back is there. If it return success I want to add a class to my button like `$(this).addClass('abc');` but of no use.
`$(this)` is not working in AJAX. What is the alternate method to do this, because there are several same blocks.

Comment: Cache `this` in a variable before doing the ajax request.

Comment: Maybe you can show code snippets from your button click?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you are inside of the AJAX callback `this` does not point to your button any more (google "JavaScript closures and this" for more).

You need to save the reference to the current `this` into a variable and then use that to add classes. Something like this:

```
$( '#button' ).click ( function () {
  var $this = $( this );
  $.get (
    'url',
    function ( data ) {
      $this.addClass ( 'abc' );
    }
  );
} );
```

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. this is not accessible inside the ajax call as it is a reference to the ajax object. You can however save it as another variable and use that within the callback.

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/gZ8qB/

```
$("#mybutton").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
        }
    }).done(function ( data ) {
        $this.addClass("done");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

save `$(this)` to a variable.. and use that

try this

```
var $this=$(this);
```

make a ajax call.. and use

```
 $this.addClass("done");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$(this)` object is not defined in the callback function of an AJAX call. If you need to reference the original element that triggered the call, you can assign it to a variable in the event handler function, making it also available within the scope of the callback function.

For example (using the `$.get` shorthand):

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function() {
    var some_button = $(this); // Assign the variable in the event handler
    $.get('some_url',{some_ariable:'some_value'}, function(data) {
         some_button.addClass('some_class'); // some_button is now also in the scope of the AJAX callback function
    });
});
```

This concept is called `closures`, wherein `"functions have access to variables that were available in the scope where the function was created"`. See [jQuery's - Javascript 101](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/closures/) for more on this subject.