# Is moving common js code to functions prevented by reliance on the closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

This might be a stupid question, but I can't seem to leverage google because of all the "Closure 101" links...

In summary, given duplicate code that relies on the closure context, is there a way to de-dup the code into a function call while still having the new function rely only on the closure rather than passing everything it needs via parameters?

A rough code example might look like:

```
function doWork(){
    // initialize variables
    // manipulate variables
    // ...

    $.ajax({
       //...
       success: function(data){
           // DUPLICATE CODE INSTANCE 1 HERE
           // RELIES ON VARIABLES IN THE CLOSURE          
       }
    });

    // More code

    $.ajax({
       //...
       success: function(data){
           // DUPLICATE CODE INSTANCE 2 HERE
           // RELIES ON VARIABLES IN THE CLOSURE          
       }
    });

}
```

As far as I know, if I de-dup the logic in the success blocks into

```
function onSuccess(...){
   // ...
}
```

Then onSuccess is no longer part of the closure, so would need all the closure variables passed as parameters where the current logic is using the closure to access.

Am I wrong about how closures work?  Is there a way to "pass the closure" to the onSuccess function rather than passing individual variables?

Comment: i fear to upvote so i do not ruin you score..

Comment: =)  It's been stuck at 666 for quite a while...

Comment: +1, you're previous score made me nervous

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working - this will help out too

Answer (score 4):

You are not wrong about the closure behavior.  What you can do is declare the `onSuccess` function inside of `doWork`.

```
function doWork(...) {
  function onSuccess(...) {
    // ...
  }

  $.ajax({
    //...
    success: onSuccess
  });

  $.ajax({
    //...
    success: onSuccess
  });
}
```

Comment: Just need to keep in mind that onSuccess will have a different value for this than when you define it. you can set the context in the ajax options, or $.proxy into it, or pass it a bound function.. lots of ways around that.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you define it inside the closure

```
function doWork(){
    // initialize variables
    // manipulate variables
    // ...
    function onSuccess(data){
       // DUPLICATE CODE INSTANCE 2 HERE
       // RELIES ON VARIABLES IN THE CLOSURE 
     }


    $.ajax({
       //...
       success: onSuccess
    });

    // More code

    $.ajax({
       //...
       success: onSuccess
    });

}
```

Comment: Part of the desire is that the doWork function is getting huge to begin with... I wanted onSuccess to be outside to clean up the code base

Comment: Also, are variables in doWork that are initialized after the definition of onSuccess still accessible to onSuccess' closure?

Comment: Yes, all variables inside `doWork` are accessible by `onSuccess`.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is turn the things you need into the JavaScript equivalent of `public` variables by using `this.var`. Then you could pass a reference of `this` to an object outside the scope of your closure and access the properties and methods of the closure that you passed (from `this`). Take the following code for example:

Edited from @danp's guidance:

```
var Work = function Work() {   
    this.closureVar = "hello";

    this.closureOnSuccess = function () {
        console.log("Inner call:" + this.closureVar);
    }

    this.someCall = function() {
        globalOnSuccess(this); //Give the global function a reference to this closure
        this.closureOnSuccess();
    }

    this.someCall();
}

var globalOnSuccess = function (context) { //context is a reference to a closure
    console.log("Outer call:" + context.closureVar); 
}; //Globally scoped function

var work = new Work();
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/g3V7L/1/)

And another example:

```
var Work = function Work() {};

Work.prototype = {
    closureVar: "hello",
    closureOnSuccess: function () {
        console.log("Inner call:" + this.closureVar);
    },
    someCall: function () {
        globalOnSuccess(this);
        this.closureOnSuccess();
    }
};

var globalOnSuccess = function (context) {
    console.log("Outer call:" + context.closureVar);
};

var work = new Work();

work.someCall();
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/g3V7L/2/)

Comment: When you call a function like that, this is the global object (window in a browser) - that's not a good thing. You probably want to make a constructor, and add those members to its prototype, instead of slamming it all into global.

Comment: as in, after you run doWork(), your global object will have closureVar, someCall etc defined _outside_ your function.

Comment: It's not hard to actually stop coding like that, you know ;) You're almost there, just need to read up on this stuff: http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/ for example. try it, you'll surprise yourself.

Comment: @danp, I think I understand. Good link. Is the new code any better?

Comment: you need to really lock down what you mean by inner and outer variables, but it's the right path.