# AJAX change HTML of Element on succes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a AJAX call that finds any elements with the class `videoReplace`

```
  jQuery('.videoReplace').each(function(index) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://optinsmart.com/videos.php',
        cache: false,
        data:{
            'video': jQuery( this ).attr('video-source')
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success:function(data){
            jQuery('#'+jQuery( this ).attr('id')).html(data);       
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

  });
```

Here is my HTML

```
<h2>Tanya &amp; Matt Ice Cream</h2>
<div id="tanya" id-name="tanya" class="videoReplace" video-source="Opt-in Smart review by Tanya_Matt Ice cream"></div>
```

in theory this code should post to my video page and the video playing is sent back in html. Then i want to add the html to the div that im working with.

it tells me that `jQuery('#'+jQuery( this ).attr('id'))` is undefinded

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't `jQuery('#'+jQuery( this ).attr('id'))` the same as `jQuery( this )` ?

Comment: exact duplicate of [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

Comment: its isnt doing anything even if i use `jQuery(this)`

Comment: Could you explain what `jQuery('#'+jQuery( this ).attr('id'))` does in your own words? And maybe you see then why this is unnecessarily convoluted :)

Comment: it was a further try at getting the element when `jQuery(this)` wasnt working. Seemed bad but i was testing. i see that it was the exact same as `jQuery(this)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `this` in the `success` callback is not the same as the `this` in the context of the `each` callback.

Comment: that was the problem, i had to set the context. Thnak you