# Changing text of a button on clicking

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to change the text of a button when clicked after doing an ajax call. Why doesn't this work?

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="register-button">REGISTER</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".register-button").click(function () 
{
    $.ajax({
        //some ajax stuff
    }).
    success(function(){
        console.log("done");
        $(this).html("Registered");
        //$(this).hide(); doesn't work either
    });
});
```

Comment: Does the text appear in console?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working

Comment: add `context: this,' inside ajax, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2j8Lrbhq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside `success` is not the button. Try this - excuse the pun:

```
$(".register-button").click(function () 
{
        var thisButton = this;

        $.ajax({
            //some ajax stuff
        }).
        success(function(){
            console.log("done");
            $(thisButton).html("Registered");
            //$(this).hide(); doesn't work either
        });
});
```

Comment: Totally missed it! Thank you!

Comment: @zack no problem, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside your `success` callback, is the object which passed to `$.ajax`. You should keep reference to your element before:

```
$(".register-button").click(function () {
    var $elem = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        //some ajax stuff
    }).success(function(){
        console.log("done");
        $elem.html("Registered");
        $elem.hide();
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0hss69b/).

Answer (score 1):

this takes on new scope. So store it before the function declaration:

```
$(".register-button").click(function () 
{
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        //some ajax stuff
    }).
    success(function(){
        console.log("done");
        $(that).html("Registered");
        //$(that).hide(); should work
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$(".register-button").click(function () {
        var that=this;
        $.ajax({
            //some ajax stuff
            success:function(){
                console.log("done");
                $(that).html("Registered");
                $(that).hide();
            });
        })
});
```