# Function in object is being declared as not a function

Tags: javascript, function, object

so I have created a small table row generator from JSON. When I started building it I hadn't put it in an object and it worked absolutley fine.

After, I made it so it could be abstract and just needes parameters passed to it. Then I put it in an object so that I could easily re use it for other sets of data. However, after putting it in an object I get the console message:

```
TypeError: this.getTableRow is not a function
```

But... it is a function:

```
getTableRow: function(data) {
    row = "<tr>";

    for (i in data) {
        row += "<td>" + data[i] + "</td>";
    }

    row += "</tr>";

    return row;
}
```

Here is the full script so you have it in context:

```
var dataCollector = {

    baseDataURL: 'http://tourn.dev/data/',

    displayDataTable: function(dataPath, tableIdentifier, dataKeys, dataOpts) {

        $.getJSON(this.buildPath(dataPath, dataOpts), function (dataset) {
            for (k in dataset) {

                d = dataset[k];

                data = [];

                for (i in dataKeys) {
                    data[i] = d[dataKeys[i]];
                }
                ;

                $(tableIdentifier).append(this.getTableRow(data));
            }
        })
    },

    getDataURL: function() {
        return this.baseDataURL;
    },

    buildPath: function(dataPath, dataOpts) {
        path = this.getDataURL();

        if (dataPath != null) {
            path += dataPath;
        }

        if (dataOpts != null) {
            if (dataOpts.constructor === Array) {
                for (i in dataOpts) {
                    path += '/' + dataOpts[i];
                }
            } else {
                path += '/' + dataOpts;
            }
        }

        return path;
    },

    getTableRow: function(data) {
        row = "<tr>";

        for (i in data) {
            row += "<td>" + data[i] + "</td>";
        }

        row += "</tr>";

        return row;
    }
};
```

Comment: In this line: `$(tableIdentifier).append(this.getTableRow(data));` keyword `this` is not what you would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.getTableRow` is not anything inside the getJSON context. Store `this` outside the call.

```
displayDataTable: function(dataPath, tableIdentifier, dataKeys, dataOpts) {
    var self = this; // store this
    $.getJSON(this.buildPath(dataPath, dataOpts), function (dataset) {
        for (k in dataset) {

            d = dataset[k];

            data = [];

            for (i in dataKeys) {
                data[i] = d[dataKeys[i]];
            }
            ;

            $(tableIdentifier).append(self.getTableRow(data)); //this in correct scope
        }
    })
}
```

More info about scope here: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `$.getJSON` callback, `this` does not refer to `dataCollector`, but to the jqXHR object.

Please see [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196) for solutions.

Also related: [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6394812/218196)

Answer (score 0):

It's because each function you create have different `this` context, if it's not an object then it's global window object, unless you have strict mode, try to use `dataCollector` isntead of this.

```
var dataCollector = {

    baseDataURL: 'http://tourn.dev/data/',

    displayDataTable: function(dataPath, tableIdentifier, dataKeys, dataOpts) {

        $.getJSON(this.buildPath(dataPath, dataOpts), function (dataset) {
            for (k in dataset) {

                d = dataset[k];

                data = [];

                for (i in dataKeys) {
                    data[i] = d[dataKeys[i]];
                }
                ;

                $(tableIdentifier).append(dataCollector.getTableRow(data));
            }
        })
    },
```