# $(this) not triggering in ajax success even after assigning value to DOM outside of ajax call

Tags: jquery

Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

I am assigning `this` to a `var element`

```
var element = this;
```

Before the AJAX call this works fine and is called properly

```
$(element).parent('.refreshstats').html('<i class="fa fa-refresh refresh-stats fa-spin" id="'+id+'" url="'+url+'"></i>');
```

If I try and call it again in the success callback it does not trigger

```
$(element).parent('.refreshstats').html('<i class="fa fa-refresh refresh-stats" id="'+id+'" url="'+url+'"></i>');
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click', '.refresh-stats', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var url = $(this).attr('url');
    var element = this;
    $(element).parent('.refreshstats').html('<i class="fa fa-refresh refresh-stats fa-spin" id="'+id+'" url="'+url+'"></i>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "refresh-stats.php",
        data:({id: id, url: url}),
        success: function(data) {
            $(element).parent('.refreshstats').html('<i class="fa fa-refresh refresh-stats" id="'+id+'" url="'+url+'"></i>');
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (result[0] == 'No') {
                $('.indexed[data-pk="'+id+'"]').html('<span class="label label-danger">No</span>')
            }
            if (result[0] == 'Yes') {
                $('.indexed[data-pk="'+id+'"]').html('<span class="label label-success">Yes</span>')
            }
            if (result[1] == 'No') {
                $('.dindexed[data-pk="'+id+'"]').html('<span class="label label-danger">No</span>')
            }
            if (result[1] == 'Yes') {
                $('.dindexed[data-pk="'+id+'"]').html('<span class="label label-success">Yes</span>')
            }
            if (result[2] == 'No') {
                $('.removed[data-pk="'+id+'"]').html('<span class="label label-danger">No</span>')
            }
            if (result[2] == 'Yes') {
                $('.removed[data-pk="'+id+'"]').html('<span class="label label-success">Yes</span>')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure the control is going inside `success`??

Comment: not sure what you mean, I am calling it again in success as you can see in my code

Comment: Is the success method fired?

Comment: Yes success is fired, if I do an `alert("test");` in success I get the alert

Comment: any `console error`?

Comment: The click event is written on `'.refresh-stats'` and the `parent()` also has `'.refresh-stats'`. Is this correct? Does the clicked element and its parent have same classes?

Comment: Provide relevant HTML markup in question itself. @ShaunakD Not same class: `'.refresh-stats'` vs `'.refreshstats'` but could be a typo i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff, ah, sorry. Did not catch that.

Comment: you missed the `-` between the two classes one is `refreshstats` and the other is `refresh-stats`. I meant it that way. Remember the first one fires fine so I know its working, its the second one that does not

Comment: Could you try `console.log($(element))` in `success:` and see what do you get?

Comment: error is `Cannot read property 'click' of undefined`

Comment: @CesarBielich But which line throws this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an XY-problem.

You likely want to just change class - also you MUST use the correct class name - I used `.refresh-stats` since you got an error on `.refreshstats`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.refresh-stats', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var url = $(this).attr('url');
    var $element = $(this); // store the jQuery object
    $(this).addClass("fa-spin"); // set the spinner
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "refresh-stats.php",
        data:({id: id, url: url}),
        success: function(data) {
            $element.removeClass("fa-spin"); // remove the spinner
```

Also I recommend to change the document in

`$(document).on('click', '.refresh-stats', function() {`

to the selector of a static parent element since it is more effecient

Answer (score 2):

Before you make the request you are replacing the html of `element.parent()`

At that point `element` no longer exists in the DOM

Suggest you store reference to the parent instead since it is not being removed

```
$(document).on('click', '.refresh-stats', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var url = $(this).attr('url');
    var $parent = $( this).parent('.refreshstats');// don't really need class for `parent()`
    $parent.html('......');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "refresh-stats.php",
        data:({id: id, url: url}),
        success: function(data) {
            $parent.html(......
```

Comment: You need to make sure it is refresh-stats or refreshstats