# jQuery Ajax callback doesn't recognise $(this) object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, this

It it my code

```
$(".library-fields-container div.field-content img").click(function(){
    var nid = getImageNodeID($(this).siblings(".image-span").text());
    $.ajax({
        url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'view_name=fehrest&view_display_id=block_1&view_args='+nid,
        success: function(response) {
            var output = response[1].data;
            alert(output);  
            $(this).hide();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('An error occured!');
        }
      });
});
```

I'm sure the `output` variable prints something and it is not empty, because the alert function displays it's content.

The problem is it doesn't hide the `$(this)` while when I put the

```
$(this).hide();
```

At the beginning of the click event just before the Ajax call it hides the image.

What is the Ajax callback function with `$(this)` object?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6394812/218196). Please use the search before asking a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context - `this` is not an element.
Save before ajax call `this` to `self` variable. Like

```
var self = this;
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(response) {
        var output = response[1].data;
        alert(output);  
        $(self).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".library-fields-container div.field-content img").click(function(){
var target = $(this);
var nid = getImageNodeID($(this).siblings(".image-span").text());
$.ajax({
    url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'view_name=fehrest&view_display_id=block_1&view_args='+nid,
    success: function(response) {
        var output = response[1].data;
        alert(output);  
        target.hide();
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('An error occured!');
    }
  });
});
```