# Submit form after event.preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I know this question has been asked a million times but i just cant seem to make it work. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
$('#frm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    var email = $('input#email').val();
    if (email == '') {
        alert('Please enter your email address');
        $('input#email').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        $.post('http://www.domain.com/', formData, function() {
            $('#frm').submit();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem???

Comment: the data gets posted to the other domain but the actual form doesn't submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the FORM using DOM node submit method:

```
$.post('http://www.domain.com/', formData, function() {
    this.submit(); // 'this' not '$(this)'
}.bind(this)); // 'bind' to set relevant context, or use jq $.proxy(handler, this) to support older browsers
```

Comment: this didn't work...the data gets posted just fine but the form doesn't submit to the action. I also meant to put $('#frm').submit() and not $(this).submit().

Comment: It works for me using `bind(this)` and `this.submit();`

Answer (score 0):

This code does not make sense

```
    $.post('http://www.domain.com/', formData, function() {
        $(this).submit();
    });
```

you are posting and then, when the request returns with success, you are trying to call submit on the form again?

by the way, `this` in that context refers to the jqXHR object of the Ajax call and not to the form. See [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

Comment: I'm trying to post data to another domain and at the same time submit the actual form.

Answer (score 0):

As most of the answers said, `this` is not a reference to the form. Then you will need to create a reference for it as follows (see `that` var). HOwever that is only needed if you want to use it later in the `success` callback:

```
$('#frm').submit(function(event) {

    // Create a reference to your form
    var that = this;

    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    var email = $('input#email').val();
    if (email == '') {
        alert('Please enter your email address');
        $('input#email').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        $.post('http://www.domain.com/', formData, function() {

            // On success response do your stuff here and 
            // submit to your 'own domain'  
            // In case you don't have the action attr, give a value to this var.
            var url = $(that).attr('action'); 
            $.post(url, formData, function() {
                // On success response do your stuff here
            });
        });
    }
});
```