# How to correctly do a jquery request in application.js using Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to relocate table row into another `<div>` through checkbox and I hope to accomplish this using Ajax call. But things won't work for me. Nothing happens after I click, there is no simply response. What am I missing?

My Javascript code in **application.js**

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $('.check').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    user_id = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
    complete = true;
    path = '/users/' + user_id + '/tasks/' + id;
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
                 method: 'put',
                 dataType: "application/json",
                 url: path,
                 data: { task: {complete: complete, id: id}  }
    });

    jqXHR.done(function(data){
         task = $(this).closest("tr");
         $('.complete-tasks').last().after(task);
    })
  };
})
})
```

view file **_index.html**

```
<h3>Tasks database</h3>

<table>

  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <tr class='tasks' id="task_<%= task.id %>">

    #Some stuff

  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class='check' data-id="<%= task.id %>" data-user-id="<%= current_user.id %>" data-complete="<%= task.complete %>" >
  </td>

    </tr>

  <% end %>

</table>

<h3>Completed</h3>

<div class="complete-tasks">
</div>
```

I'm referring to an update action in my
**tasks_controller.rb**

```
 def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
     if @task.update(task_params)
      format.json { head :no_content }
     else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
     end
   end
  end


 private

    def task_params
     params.require(:task).permit(:title, :due_date, :priority, :complete)
    end

end
```

**rake routes**
[image]

Comment: What does the javascript console say? Is there an error? Also try checking your log file before and after the click to see if the request hits Rails and if there's any errors there.

Comment: You should avoid using `$(this)` inside your done callback. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working

Comment: @mccannf I'm very grateful. Supply an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @eirikir There weren't any errors in console. mccannf tip resolved my problem.

Comment: @eirikir and I'm just curious how to check log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `$(this)` inside an ajax callback like `done`. In your case it will not refer to the checkbox anymore but rather the jqXhr object.

See this question for details:
[$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)