# jQuery custom function wrong "this" reference

Tags: jquery, function, reference, this

I need to execute the same code in jQuery multiple times so i decided to make my own jQuery function.

It looks like this so far:

```
                jQuery.fn.extend({
                fooFunction: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        url: "includes/thescript.php",
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            $(this).html(data);
                        }, complete: function () {
                            // do sth
                        }
                    });
                    return $(this);
                }
            });
```

But now i have the problem, that "this" seems to refer to the wrong instance, while using it here in the success function "**$(this).html(data);**".

**When i use the ID instead**, e.g. $("#TheID").html(data); it works, but why not with "this"?

**Between:** I call the function with:
$("#TheID").fooFunction()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the scope of `this` changes when you're inside the anonymous function you provide to the `success` parameter. To solve the problem you can store the `this` reference from the outer scope in a variable, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    fooFunction: function () {
        var $el = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "includes/thescript.php",
            success: function (data) {
                $el.html(data);
            }, 
            complete: function () {
                // do something
            }
        });
        return $el;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In a jQuery ajax callback, "**this**" is a reference to the options used in the ajax request. It's not a reference to a DOM element.

For more information visit this link [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394826/2798643)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the function cache `$(this)` and then use that instead.

`this` in the function reference to the function context not the element targeted.

Try this.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    fooFunction: function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "includes/thescript.php",
            success: function (data)
            {
                $this.html(data);
            }, complete: function () {
                // do sth
            }
        });
        return $this;
    }
});
```