# Trouble passing/accessing element via ajax context

Tags: jquery

I've read the documentation regarding the [context setting of jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

When the DOM manipulation is triggered outside of the ajax call, the DOM is successfully affected:

```
var element = $('#logo');
element.addClass('good');
console.log(element);
$.ajax({
  context: element,
  url: 'myfile.json',
  type:'get',
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(data) {    
    //reserved
  }
});
```

When I move the DOM manipulation inside the ajax call, the expected result shows in the console output but is *not* actually reflected in the DOM:

```
var element = $('#logo');
$.ajax({
  context: element,
  url: 'myfile.json',
  type:'get',
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(data) {    
    $(this).addClass('good');
    console.log($(this));
  }
});
// [h1#logo.good, selector: "#logo", context: document]
```

I have also tried referencing 'element' instead of $(this) without success:

```
var element = $('#logo');
$.ajax({
  context: element,
  url: 'myfile.json',
  type:'get',
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(data) {    
    element.addClass('good');
    console.log(element);
  }
});
// [h1#logo.good, selector: "#logo", context: document]
```

It seems odd that the context in the console output is 'document' rather than '#logo'. In any case, the element reference seems to get lost as soon as it's inside the ajax call.

I have tried all three of the solutions in the accepted answer of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working) to no avail.

Any ideas? I'm going gray.

Comment: The `context` of the `#logo` element is `document`; that is expected result. You have not changed the context of `#logo` element; you have changed `context` of `$.ajax()` to `#logo`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to manipulate an element from within the success callback. Ideally, from within the success callback, I will pass the element to a function for manipulation.

Comment: Yes, which portion of `js` is not returning expected results?

Comment: The first example appears to meet requirement?

Comment: _"I get the feeling you haven't read the entire question. "_
Re-read Question on several occasions. Are you stating that `this` is not `#logo` within `$.ajax()` `success` callback at second example at Question?
_"The element reference seems to get lost as soon as it's inside the ajax success call"_ Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently mistaking `context` option of `$.ajax()` for `context` of `jQuery()`. They are different.

`context` of [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

> context
>
> Type: PlainObject
>
> This object will be the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that
>   represents the Ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged
>   with the settings passed to `$.ajax`). For example, specifying a DOM
>   element as the context will make that the context for the `complete`
>   callback of a request, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

set `this` object at `$.ajax()` callbacks. `context` of [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery)

> context
>
> Type: Element or jQuery
>
> A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to
>   use as context
>
> Selector Context
>
> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the `$()` function. > For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be restricted like so:

```
$( "div.foo" ).click(function() {
  $( "span", this ).addClass( "bar" );
});
```

Comment: @Stephen Setting the `context` of `#logo` to `#logo` would effectively be call at `$()` for `#logo` to search for the `#logo` element as a child of itself; where `#logo` is an `id` , there should not be duplicate `id`s in `document`, result would be `var element = $('#logo', document.getElementById("logo"));` returning a jQuery object without `#logo` element being selected `[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: div#logo, selector: "#logo"]`; as `#logo` `context` would be the `parent` element. Though you could set `context` to `.parent`, of `#logo` to return `#logo` element

Comment: If you look at my second code block, I am using `context` of `$.ajax()` as you have described. I am not setting the context of #logo…

Comment: @Stephen Yes, your second example should return expected result? Not certain what the issue is you are trying to convey?