# Refer to element by using $(this) in ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to use the `$(this)`-selector in the ajax success function to select the element `.selectclass` which was doubleclicked before. However, this doesn't work. Is it possible to select in the ajax success function?

jQuery:

```
$(document.body).on("dblclick",".selectclass",function(){
    bla = $(this).attr("class").slice(5); //works fine
    $.ajax({
        url: 'bla.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {
            'bla':bla
        },
        success: function(reply) {
            if((reply == "blabla")
            {
                $(this).siblings().find(".likes, .likes1").slideToggle('slow'); //not working 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cache the variable.

```js
$(document.body).on("dblclick", ".selectclass", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var bla = $this.attr("class").slice(5); //works fine
  $.ajax({
    url: 'bla.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'bla': bla
    },
    success: function(reply) {
      if (reply == "blabla") {
        $this.siblings().find(".likes, .likes1").slideToggle('slow'); // will work now 
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Please use `var` for local variables. Also you have a typo after `if`.

```
if((reply == "blabla") // Remove the double parenthesis.
```

Comment: You might as well cache it before you use it but +1

Comment: @DelightedD0D That line is a test line by OP right, so I ignored it. Right? `:)`

Comment: Use `var` please!

Comment: Lol, yup, indeed, my bad, just saw the two `$(this)` next to each other and it looked odd.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Updated. I don't see why not use the global scope. Anyways.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe Praveen writes as much php as I do, I catch myself doing that all the time!

Comment: _"I don't see why not use the global scope"_ :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry `:(`

Comment: Thank you soo much! Sat quite a while working on this and didn't find anything on the internet either... :) will accept your answer asap

Comment: @Moritz You are welcome... `:)` Waiting for 5 mins... `:D`

Comment: @Moritz just to mention it, in case it isnt clear *why*, ["Inside the callback, this refers to the jqXHR object of the Ajax call, not the element the event handler was bound to"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6394826/1376624)

Comment: @Moritz See the above link by D0D as well. Looks interesting... `:)`

Comment: Can also use the `context` option for `$.ajax` ... `context:this`

Comment: @charlietfl Yea, that's what the above comment says... `:D`