# jQuery data value not updating. How to resolve this?

Tags: jquery, html

jQuery code:

```
if($(this).attr('data-status') == 'Yes'){
    alert('if');
    $(this).attr("data-status","No");
}
else{
    alert('else');
    $(this).attr("data-status","Yes");
}
```

jQuery function code:

```
$(".Notification").click(function(){
  var notification = {
    petid: $(this).attr('data-value'),
    status: $(this).attr('data-status')
  }
  var formurl = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Dashboard/notification';
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: formurl,
    data: notification,
    success: function(response){
        if($(this).attr('data-status') == 'Yes'){
            alert('if');
            $(this).attr("data-status","No");
        }
        else{
            alert('else');
            $(this).attr("data-status","Yes");
        }
    }
  })
})
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="Notification" data-value="6" data-status="Yes" checked="">
```

I am trying to update the value of data-status but it not working. It alerting me if or else. but not updating value.

Comment: BTW... what's your *success* `response` used for?

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` will not refer to your element inside the success so define `$(this)` at the top of the click event.

The `change` **event** should be used for checkboxes (since a `click` is not needed to trigger a checkbox change event)

```
$(".Notification").on("change", function() {

  var ThisIt = $(this);

  var notification = {
    petid: ThisIt.attr('data-value'),
    status: ThisIt.attr('data-status')
  }

  var formurl = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Dashboard/notification';

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: formurl,
    data: notification,
    success: function(response){
        if(ThisIt.attr('data-status') == 'Yes'){
            alert('if');
            ThisIt.attr("data-status","No");
        }
        else{
            alert('else');
            ThisIt.attr("data-status","Yes");
        }
    }
  })
})
```

for more information you can take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394826/3385827