# How to recup the .data of an element that has been clicked ? (javascript, not working atm)

Tags: javascript, html

i'm currently working on an online project which is a Tarot game (card game) in single page application. And the thing is, in order to play, the player needs to click on a card, which is here in my case an img, and it should execute a fonction getting thedatas that I put in earlier when I dynamically generated the cards.

However, when I try to click, it calls the function but I get a console.log() undefined instead of the awaited data.

Here is my code generating a card :

```js
let ajouterImageCarte = function (carte, destination) {
        let img = $('<img />');
        $(destination).append(
            img.attr("src", carte.url)
                .attr("class", "imageCarte")
                .data("valeur", carte.valeur)
                .data("couleur", carte.couleur)
                .data("nom", carte.nom)
                .click(clickImgage)
        );
    };
```

And here is the function called after a click :

```js
let clickImgage = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/php/json/getTourEtatJeu.php'
        })
            .done(function (dataEtat) {
                if (dataEtat.isMonTour && "chien" === dataEtat.etatPartie) {
                    console.log("yes");
                    if (1<2) {
                        let nom = $(this).data("nom");
                        console.log(nom);
                        let carte = new Carte(nom);
                        chien.push(carte);
                        $(this).fadeOut(function () {
                            let img = $('<img />');
                            $('#plateau').append(
                                img.attr("src", carte.url)
                                    .attr("class", "imageCarte")
                                    .data("valeur", carte.valeur)
                                    .data("couleur", carte.couleur)
                                    .data("nom", carte.nom)
                                    .click(clickImgage)
                            );
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("no");
                    }
                }
                else if (dataEtat.isMonTour && "jeuEnCours" === dataEtat.etatPartie) {

                }
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("Problème survenu lors du clic sur une carte !!");
            });
        return false;
    };
```

The important part of the function is at the beginning, after the ajax call, where I try to console.log(nom), which is let nom = $(this).data("nom");.

I've already tried some stuff and looked in stack overflow questions and other websites but I didn't manage to find an answer for this strange problem. 
Besides, I could really use some help right now because I need to finish this project today and this point is the only point that doesnt work.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: try `.attr("data")`

Answer (score 0):

there are some not understandable for me issues with retrieving by `.data()` method with jquery

1. in most of cases just `.data()` works fine
2. you can try `.attr("data-valeur")` method with 'data' option
3. you can also use directly `.dataset` property from an html element

Answer (score 0):

In your callback, `this` doesn't refer to the clicked image as you expect. See the answers here : [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

Comment: Thnaks, i'm going to check this

Comment: Ok thanks, it's working now after adding contex to ajax. You saved my day ;)