# Jquery: How to set some value for current TD

Tags: jquery

I have a html table with few columns and rows. in each row there is a button in a TD. when button will be clicked then i want to set some text into current or closest td of button.

This way i tried but nothing happening when button clicked.

```
$('#tblAppointments').on('click', '#btnbook', function () {

$(this).closest('td').html('Booked');

$(this).parent.html('Booked');

});
```

### Table HTML

```
<table id="tblAppointments" class="table table-striped">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
    <th scope="col">Doctor Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Available Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Available Time</th>
    <th scope="col">Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input id="hdndocid" value="1" type="hidden">
<input id="hdnpatientemail" value="popy@gmail.com" type="hidden">Dr Debasis Saha</td>
<td>27/05/2018</td>
<td>10:10 A.M.</td>
<td><button id="btnbook" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Book Now</button></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This code is not working. I want to remove button from td and set some text like Booked. what is mistake in my code.

### EDIT

See how i am doing full code

```
$('#tblAppointments').on('click', '.btnbook', function () {
    var rowid = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[id*='hdndocid']").val();
    var email = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[id*='hdnpatientemail']").val();
    //$(this).closest('td').html('Booked');

    var baseurl = '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddress"]' + 'api/Appointments/BookAppointment';
    //alert(baseurl);
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ email: email, rowid: rowid }),
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            if(data=='SUCCESS');
            {
                $(this).closest('td').html('Booked');
                return false;

            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert('Error ' + err.Message);
            console.log(textStatus);
        }

    }).done(function () {

    });
});
```

if i write these line at top of button click then it is working

```
                    $(this).closest('td').html('Booked');
                    return false;
```

but when i put this line inside jquery ajax success then it is not working

```
 success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        if(data=='SUCCESS');
                        {
                            $(this).closest('td').html('Booked');
                            return false;

                        }
                    },
```

Please suggest what to do as a result code should work inside success.

Comment: Do you have more than one `id="btnbook"`? IDs are required to be unique. Use a class instad.

Comment: If that's not the problem, add your HTML to the question. Make it an executable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: html table added. i want when i will click button in td then button will be removed from td and a text will be added in that td.

Comment: @Barmar i used class but still no luck. here is my  code `$('#tblAppointments').on('click', '.btn-info', function () {
$(this).closest('td').html('Booked');

$(this).parent.html('Booked');

});`

Comment: Code works fine using class instead of id https://jsfiddle.net/xey0qz13/1/

Comment: Note that `parent` is a jQuery method...not a property. Should see error in browser console trying `$(this).parent.html('Booked'); `

Comment: @charlietfl i test your code it is working but the same is not working at my side. i am using version jquery-1.10.2.js it has any issue. you used different version.

Comment: Version shouldn't matter so long as it's not really old and doesn't support `on()` which yours does. Any errors in console? Does table exist when you run that code?

Comment: @charlietfl please see my edit section where i describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: Ahhh...because `this` inside success callback isn't what you think it is. See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: i tried this code this.closest('td').html('Booked'); but still not luck from jquery ajax success. so give me bit code which tell me what to change.

Comment: Read that link. Store a reference to `this` outside of the `$.ajax` to use inside the callback

Comment: Or can also add option to $.ajax `context:this`

Comment: yes worked i store $(this) to self variable and later call like this from ajax success self.closest('td').html('Booked'); and it worked. thanks a lot for your time and guidance.

Comment: @charlietfl i am eager to know why $(this) will not work in ajax success callback....please share the knowledge. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table has more than one row, having more than one element with the same `id` is invalid html, and you should use a class selector instead:

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnbook">Book Now</button>
</td>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#tblAppointments').on('click', '.btnbook', function () {
            $(this).closest('td').text('Booked');
        });   
    });
</script>
```

(and `$(this).parent.html('Booked');` if you do use it, should be `$(this).parent().html('Booked');` but the `.closest('td')` will select the closest `'td'` up the chain in any case so it is not needed, based on your html).

If you've referenced jQuery correctly, and you do not have another element with the `id = tblAppointments`, this should work.

**Based on your updated code**, put this code ahead of `$.ajax`:

```
var _this = $(this);
```

and change the success function to be:

```
_this.closest('td').html('Booked');
```

Comment: same is not working at my side. i am using version jquery-1.10.2.js it has any issue. you used different version

Comment: It should work if things are set up correctly - jQuery version should be ok - make sure the reference to the jQuery source file is in the <head> section, and make sure you don't have any duplicate ids on the page. The only other issues could be if the table is in a modal (I'm assuming it's not ..?) - and make sure the script is wrapped in the document.ready function I gave in the answer. Double check these things and it should work.

Comment: please see my edit section where i describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: I've updated the answer - your reference to $(this) should be defined before entering $.ajax

Comment: i am eager to know why $(this) will not work in ajax success callback....please share the knowledge. thanks

Comment: Inside the success function (which is a callback), "this" refers to the jqXHR object of the Ajax call, not the element the event handler was bound to - see [this more complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394826/5957979) for more info