# Cannot assign public variable from a function in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using cordova AppCenter Shared plugin inside Ionic4 app and calling function, I was able to get ID in console, but cannot assign it to public variable, any ideas?:

Stack: Angular 6

```html
public deviceId: string = '';

this._window.AppCenter.getInstallId(function(success, error) {
          console.log(success);
          this.deviceId = success;        
      });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this._window.AppCenter.getInstallId(success => {
      console.log(success);
      this.deviceId = success;        
});
```

For more detail, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **`arrow function`** in this case, because using this refers to the function context.

```
this._window.AppCenter.getInstallId(success => {
     this.deviceId = success;        
});
```

You can refer the answer **[`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)**