# Get proper form id format that is loaded dynamically after ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know that it is better to use delegation binding for any html elements that is dynamically added. This may be simple but I don't get the proper "id" of the form element.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form#add_education", function(e){
e.preventDefault();

        console.log($(this));
        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function (json){

                    $('.view-educationsec').css('display','none');
                    $(this)[0].reset();
                    showEducation();

                    swal("Good job!", "Education saved successfully!", "success");
            },
            error: function(json){
                if (json.status === 422) {
                    // $("#errorMessage").text('There is an error occured. Please try again.');
                    swal("Something went wrong!", "Please contact the developer for this issue.", "error");
                } 

            }

        });


$("html").removeClass("no-scroll"); // para ma enable ang scroll sa browser

});
```

Console.log returns alright, but the ajax function will result to

**"Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].reset is not a function"**

I'm guessing that ajax is also not passing data to the controller because of the improper id format being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found an answer, guys. I just add a variable for form id and then apply it to the ones who are using it.

```
var form = $(this);
```

**Final updated code**

```
 $(document).on("submit", "form#add_education", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var form = $(this);
$start_date = $("input[name=start_date]").val();
   $end_date = $("input[name=end_date]").val();


        console.log($(this));
        $.ajax({
            url     : form.attr('action'),
            type    : form.attr('method'),
            data    : form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function (json){

                    $('.view-educationsec').css('display','none');
                    form[0].reset();
                    showEducation();

                    swal("Good job!", "Education saved successfully!", "success");
            },
            error: function(json){
                if (json.status === 422) {
                    // $("#errorMessage").text('There is an error occured. Please try again.');
                    swal("Something went wrong!", "Please contact the developer for this issue.", "error");
                } 

            }

        });


$("html").removeClass("no-scroll"); // para ma enable ang scroll sa browser


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this)` inside the AJAX call doesn't refer to the form element that fired the event. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working) question has a few possible solutions.

Comment: I manage to solve it a while ago. Thanks for the answer though. Now I know the reason why it doesn't work