# Django Json like button and counting likes isn't working

Tags: python, html, json, django

i'm making a like button in Django with a JSON code but i when I click the like button it doesn't increment the number of likes in this product or pass the like (as this hunter liked this product).Do I need to make a separate class for like in models.py, if so what should be in it. Or is it that the slug isn't set up the right way. In the urls.py and models.py I'm showing all the code, in views.py only the method of the like button and the imports, and in detail.html only the HTML tag's for the like button and the JSON script. I'm working with :
    Django Version: 2.2.9
    Python Version: 3.7.4 .

The models.py in the app "products":

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.urls import reverse

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    pub_date =  models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'icon/')
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:100] + "..."
    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime("%b %e %Y")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         #if not self.slug:
            #self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        if not self.slug:
            slug = slugify(self.title)
            while True:
                try:
                    product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
                    if article == self:
                        self.slug = slug
                        break
                    else:
                        slug = slug + '-'
                except:
                    self.slug = slug
                    break
        return super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

The views.py in the app "products":

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
try:
    from django.utils import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Product
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST


def home(request):
    products = Product.objects
    return render(request, 'products/home.html', {'products':products})

@login_required(login_url = '/accounts/signup')
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['body'] and request.POST['url'] and request.FILES['icon'] and request.FILES['image']:
            product = Product()
            product.title = request.POST['title']
            product.body = request.POST['body']
            if request.POST['url'].startswith('http://') or request.POST['url'].startswith('https://'):
                product.url = request.POST['url']
            else:
                product.url = 'http://' + request.POST['url']
            product.icon = request.FILES['icon']
            product.image = request.FILES['image']
            product.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            product.hunter = request.user
            product.save()
            return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))
        else:
            return render(request, 'products/create.html', {'error':'All fields are required.'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'products/create.html')

def detail(request, product_id):
    detail_product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk = product_id)
    return render(request, 'products/detail.html', {'product' : detail_product})

@login_required(login_url = '/accounts/signup')
@require_POST
def like(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hunter = request.user
        slug = request.POST.get('slug', None)
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug = slug)

        if product.likes.filter(hunter_id = hunter.id).exists():
            # user has already liked this company
            # remove like/user
            product.likes.remove(hunter)
            message = 'You disliked this'
            product.save()
        else:
            # add a new like for a company
            product.likes.add(hunter)
            message = 'You liked this'
            product.save()

    ctx = {'likes_count': product.total_likes, 'message': message}
    # use mimetype instead of content_type if django < 5
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx), content_type='application/json')
```

The urls.py in products app:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('create', views.create, name = 'create'),
    path('<int:product_id>/', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
    path('<int:product_id>/upvote', views.upvote, name = 'upvote'),
    path('user/<int:fk>', views.hunterhunts, name = 'hunterhunts'),
    path('<slug:slug>', views.like, name='like'),
]
```

The HTML file detail.html in the "products" app :

```
<input type="button" id="like" name="{{ product.slug }}" value="Like" />
                    <script>
                    $('#like').click(function() {
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{% url 'like' product.slug %}",
                        data: {
                          'slug': $(this).attr('name'),
                          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(response) {
                          alert(response.message);
                          alert('Product likes count is now ' + response.likes_count);
                        },
                        error: function(rs, e) {
                          alert(rs.responseText);
                        }
                      });
                    });
                  </script>
```

Any idea what should be corrected or added for the like button to work.

Please be explicit if you can!!!

Answer (score 0):

[$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working)

`'slug': $(this).attr('name'),`

I would either do `var self = this; before ajax or $('#like').attr('name')`

````
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hunter = request.user
        if product.likes.exists():
            if product.likes.filter(username=hunter.username).exists():
                product.likes.remove(hunter)
                message = 'You disliked this'
                product.save()
            else:
                product.likes.add(hunter)
                message = 'You liked this'
                product.save()
        else:
            product.likes.add(hunter)
            message = 'You liked this'
            product.save()

    ctx = {'likes_count': product.total_likes, 'message': message}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx), content_type='application/json')```
````

Comment: I tried what you just suggested, both of them, and it didn't work. any idea

Comment: ```import jsonfrom django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404```
not sure this is typo but error here.

Comment: yeah it's a typo when i submitted the code, in my code after import json everything is  in another line

Comment: The problem with the like button is still there, i'm open to any suggestion

Comment: Edited my answer to fix the like view .