# Send jquery request like Postman

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, http, postman

I tried to send some `post` methods from my javascript file but something goes wrong and script doesn't work. My `html` file is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8081/login",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { username: "John", password: "Boston" }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Done: " + msg );
        })
        .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I use `spring-boot` for server and want to check permission by using JWT. So I overided `attemptAuthentication` method from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` class:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    String contentType = httpServletRequest.getContentType();
    String headerPart = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Accept");
    String body = httpServletRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(httpServletRequest.getInputStream(),AccountCredentials.class);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
}
```

if I send request from `html` file `body` and `contentType` are empty  and `headerpart` is `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`

However when the request method is sended from Postman - everything works perfectly(so `contentType` is `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` and `body` is `{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}`), here is my Postman configuration:

[image]

It is possible that I misunderstood something but have no idea why my request from jquery is not the same. Is there any solutions for this?

Comment: You can try using datatype of ajax request as dataType : "text" instead of dataType : "json".The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

Comment: I tried but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Successful Postman requests indicate that your backend is properly set up.  Your request methods though might be at fault.  Remove the variable binding that you use on line 5.

[JQuery AJAX syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780038/jquery-ajax-syntax)  here is a link to a similar question. 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp a link to the w3 schools use cases.

Your code should look like this:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8081/login",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { username: "John", password: "Boston" }
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Done: " + msg );
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
});
```